# Changing form information with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, paypal

Is there a way to change the content of a form with Javascript?

I have a series of paypal buttons, but want the user to be able to shop in CAD or USD.

The form looks something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<input name="amount" value="6.99" type="hidden" />
<input name="currency_code" value="CAD" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

I need to change the value="CAD' to value="USD"

Is there any way I could have a button or some sort of 'toggle' on the site whereby users can change the currency? It should happen to each product.

I had someone implement simple cart, but they are no longer available

is there a better way to do this?( I though this might be simplest) But perhaps it should be done during checkout somehow? I presume this would be more complicated.

thanks in advance and hope I have been clear! let me know if you need more information.

my site is www.bodesi.com (if that helps)

Comment: yes, you can. via DOM operations, you can change pretty much anything, anywhere, in a document tree. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via javascript DOM.

Example: `<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByName('currency_code')[0].value='USD';">`

Comment: That works great, How do I make it such that the user would not have to do this on every product page?

Comment: You could use the PHP sessions to remember their choice.

And then you can use `<input name="currency_code" value="<?echo $_SESSION['currency_code'];?>" type="hidden" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jQuery, which it looks like your site already includes.

Here's one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/x7LDN/

```
$(function() {
    $('#change_currency').click(function(){
        $('input[name="currency_code"]').val('USD');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you requirement properly , 
Ask user somewhere for the currency

```
<select name = "currency" id='currency' >  
 <option value='USD'>USD</option>
 <option value='CAD'>CAD</option>
</select>
```

And later use the javascript on the same page  to change the value of the paypal button

If you are using jquery:

```
(function($){ 
  $("#currency").change(function(){ 
     $('input[name="currency_code"]').val($(this).val());
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

If you want to use clean javascript then

```
document.getElementById('currency').onchange =  function(){ 
  document.getElementsByName('currency_code')[0].value= this.value; 
}
```